# How to find duplicates when value is not equal to text?

Tags: excel

So... this is going to be a difficult explanation...

I am using a barcode scanner to enter a 20 digit number into Excel. Due to the limitations of Excel this has to be done as text, since Excel only allows up to 15 digits.

This means that my cell has a shown value of example 00257108402007839772 but the value "behind" the cell is  257108402007839000 (the last 3 digits are turned to zeros).

I have to check the values for duplicates, and the last digits are in most cases the digits that differentiate the numbers from each other. This means that when doing a conditional formatting on the cells, the most part of the numbers are flagged as duplicates.

So my question is basically - do you know of a way to search duplicates on the shown value, and not on the "real" value of the cell?

I hope this makes sense....

Comment: Have you tried adding `'` before scanning? Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/last-digits-changed-to-zeros so the value shown and the value "behind" cell is the same

Comment: No, i haven't tried this. But it is worth a shot, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something for you to consider:

[image]

As you can see `COUNTIF()` does not work on these values, but `SUMPRODUCT()` will when we just directly compare a range against a single cell. Below you'll see an example of conditional formatting:

[image]

Rule used on range `A1:A4`: `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$4=$A1))>1`

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. Do you have a way to exclude the empty cells in the formatted area?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you meant @ColinShields? Are you looking for something like: `=AND($A1<>"",SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$4=$A1))>1)`

Comment: That is perfect. Thanks :)